# Does anyone know where decent documentation describing the Lucene index format IN DETAIL on the web is?

Tags: search, full-text-search, lucene

I am mainly curious as to the inner workings of the engine itself. I couldnt find anything about the index format itself (IE in detail as though you were going to build your own compatible implementation) and how it works. I have poked through the code, but its a little large to swallow for what must be described somewhere since there are so many compatible ports to other languages around. Can anyone provide a decent link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen this: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/fileformats.html? It's the most detailed I've found.

Although [Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) does stop short of the detail in that link, I found it a useful companion to keep a handle on the big picture concepts while understanding the nitty gritty.

Comment: Thanks! Thats close enough to what I wanted. Much appreciated.